# Mirror Layout / Reverse Layout

Tags: basic4android

Is it possible to miror/reverse the display. I am planning to make a app where I will show the display up to the windscreen of a car.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the complete layout on a bitmap and then flip the bitmap with [Canvas.DrawBitmapFlipped](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/drawing.html#canvas_drawbitmapflipped).